# uwp some binding image source not appears bugs

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

i make a list with

```
 public class imageclass
    {
        private string gettingimage ;

        public string GettingImage
        {
            get
            {
                return gettingimage;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != gettingimage)
                {

                    gettingimage = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GettingImage"));
                    }

                    //Debug.WriteLine(GettingImage); //http://immgur.jpg/
                }
            }
        }
    }
observablecollection<imageclass> imglist = new observablecollection<imageclass>()
   var collecting = lotimageurlcollection();

   foreach(string lists in collecting.tolist()){
    imglist.add(new imageclass() { GettingImage = lists.uri});
    }
```

in xaml design
`<image source={Binding GettingImage} wide="111" height="100">`

the problem => suppose i get total : 190 binded image with uri images .

90 images appears in the listview image source and
100 images not appears

i have checked all the 190 uri by debug writeline separately that uri is ok , as i seen 190 uri is perfect with images but in my listview all images not appears,
is this bugs in uwp or ?
can someone solve this issue

Comment: Are these images on the device or on the internet?

Comment: internet => suppose a gallery http://imgur.com/gallery/YUzOO . Getting image from there

Comment: I would think you are waiting for the last 100 images to download.  You could try something the UWP community toolkit ImageEx control  to give an indication they are being downloaded http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/ImageEx/

Comment: Unfortunately the result is same ImagEx still missing lot images

Comment: the bugs in uwp xaml cachmode

Comment: I would rather suggest you to try downloading the images and binding the local images. This is more reliable approach.

Comment: Please try to list the images that does not appear in the `ListView` and the URI to set to the `Image`.

Comment: @ AbsoluteSith thanks, but the goal is only view if i download and get image from local drive not a good idea, because i want view temporary